# Tensorflow.keras のSGDのバッチについて

Tags: tensorflow, keras

SGDの引数にバッチサイズが無いのですが、どう指定すればいいですか？
`optimizer = SGD(learning_rate=0.02)` 
SGDのコードの中身を確認したのですが、Batchsizeを変更している箇所は無いように見えました
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.0/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/gradient_descent.py#L30-L194

処理は勾配法のように見えます

Batchはここで定義されているものが自動的に使われるのでしょうか

```
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train)).shuffle(10000).batch(32)
test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_test, y_test)).batch(32)
```

Answer (score 0):

バッチサイズはnay様が書かれている通り、そちらで定義されたものが使われていると思います。
TensorFlowのドキュメントでtf.keras.optimizers.SGDの項目を見ても、そのような引数はなさそうに見えます。
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/SGD